# For a specific project shape of camera is deformed

Tags: camera

My camera became just a rectangle. The main node of camera disappeared. I erase and add new camera. It is the same.[image]

Comment: Did you tamper with camera settings? Add a screenshot of them.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at overlay settings in the corner of your 3d viewport:

[image]

What you observe will happen if you have a camera selected and as the active object and overlays are disabled or Extras are disabled in the Viewport Overlays settings,  Objects section.

Comment: Thanks. Just discovered.